# Linked list and adding elements to the end of the list

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to create linked list of rectangles. I`m given the class files of` rectangle`and`point`classes, and need to write`RectNode`and`RectList`.

This is `RectNode`:

```
public class RectNode
{     
    private RectangleA _rect;
    private RectNode _next;
    
    public RectNode(RectangleA r)
    {
         _rect = r;   
         _next = null;
    }
        
    public RectNode(RectangleA r,RectNode n)    
    {    
        _rect = r;        
        _next = n;  
    }
    
    public RectNode(RectNode other) 
    {
        _rect = other._rect;
        _next =other._next;
    }
    
    public RectangleA getRect()
    {
        return _rect;
    }
        
    public RectNode getNext() 
    {
        return _next;
    }

    public void setRect(RectangleA r) 
    {
        _rect = r;
    }

    public void setNext (RectNode next) 
    {
        _next = next;
    }   
}
```

And this is part of  `RecList` which I have a problem with:

```
public class RectList
{
    private RectNode _head;
    public RectList()
    {
        _head = null;
    }
   
public void addRect(RectangleA t)
{
    RectNode value = new RectNode(t,null);
    RectNode next = new RectNode(t,_head);
    while(next.getNext() != null) 
    {
        next = next.getNext();
    }
}
```

I want the order to be first-in first-out, but managed only first-in last-out by this:

```
public void addRect(RectangleA t)
{
     RectNode next = new RectNode(t,_head);
     _head = next;
}
```

So how I do that the way I need? I tried running trough the list by `next.getNext()` until the
`next` is `null`, but can`t figure out by code and implement it.

Comment: Please reformat your code to make it more readable, e.g. remove all that excess whitespace, correct indentation etc. - it's you who wants us to invest time and effort into an answer so you should show you value that by putting time and effort into the question.

Comment: As for your question: do you understand what `RectNode next = new RectNode(t,_head);` and `RectNode value = new RectNode(t,null);` are doing and why the second parameter is different? If you want to add a node at the end you basically have to iterate until the end (that's what your loop is already doing) and then add the new node as the former last node's `next`.

Comment: There is no remove method in the code you have shared. You are only adding nodes to the list and removing none. So there is no question whether its first in first out or first in last out.

Comment: Sorry for the messy code Iv`e edited hope its better,I understand the part when i iterate to the end,but can`t code it,after I reach the end i just i tried using the RectNode constructor to create a point with the rectangle and next.getNext() but i didn`t work

Comment: The indentation of your code is bad. Do you really code like that?

Comment: ive been sitting on this for 8 hours and cant figure it out , i know my indetation is bad but can someone save me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the issues in `addRect`:

- There is no assignment of `value` to anything that relates to the list, so the node is not added.
- There is no provision to update `_head` when it was `null`
- If it was intended to create a dummy node that sits in from of `_head` (which can be a valid approach), then this idea is destroyed by walking away from that node in the loop: you have for ever lost the reference to that dummy node, yet you would need it to update `_head` (in case it was `null`)

There are several ways to do this, and I understand from your code that you want to introduce a dummy node, that sits in front of the current `_head`. But then you would need another reference to *stay* there, one that is not modified by the loop.

I would also use different variable names. `value` gives the impression that it is about a node's value, but this is not the case: it is a node -- the one to be added -- so I'd just call it `newNode` if you really need the variable at all. The name `next` suggests that it refers to something that precedes it, but that seems irrelevant here. As its purpose is to identify the tail of the list, why not call it `tail`?

#### 1. Solution using a dummy node

```
public void addRect(RectangleA t)
{
    final RectNode preHead = new RectNode(t, _head); // This reference will stay here
    RectNode tail = preHead; // This reference will traverse the list
    while (tail.getNext() != null) 
    {
        tail = tail.getNext();
    }
    // Now create and append the new node immediately after the tail node:
    tail.setNext(new RectNode(t, null));
    // Set the new head (in case it was null, this is relevant)
    _head = preHead.getNext();
}
```

#### 2. Solution without dummy node

Although the solution *with* the dummy node does not have to distinguish between the case of an empty and non-empty list, you can avoid the use of the dummy node when you *do* deal separately with these cases:

```
public void addRect(RectangleA t)
{
    if (_head == null) { // Special case, the only one where _head must change
        _head = new RectNode(t, null);
    } else { // The list is not empty, and _head will not change
        RectNode tail = _head;
        while (tail.getNext() != null) 
        {
            tail = tail.getNext();
        }
        // Now create and append the new node immediately after the tail node:
        tail.setNext(new RectNode(t, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: now all makes sense,I tried the second solution in many different ways but didn`t understand i should use tail.setNext,instead when i reach the end i wrote "new RectNode(t,null),and it only register the first rectangle in the list,thank you